# Any way for a class to prevent outside code from declaring variables of its type?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Is it possible for a class of exposing a type for function returns, without allowing users of that class to create variables of that type?  A couple usage scenarios:

1. A Fluent interface on a large class; a statement like "foo=bar.WithX(5).WithY(9).WithZ(19);" would be inefficient if it had to create three new instances of the class, but could be much more efficient if the WithX could create one instance, and the other statements could simply use it.

   A class may wish to support a statement like "foo[19].x = 9;" even when foo itself isn't an array, and does not hold the data in class instances that can be exposed to the public; one way to do that is to have foo[19] return a struct which holds a reference to 'foo' and the value '19', and has a member property 'x' which could call "foo.SetXValue(19, 9);"  Such a struct could have a conversion operator to convert itself to the "apparent" type of foo[19].

In both of these scenarios, storing the value returned by a method or property into a variable and then using it more than once would cause strange behavior.  It would be desirable if the designer of the class exposing such methods or properties could ensure that callers wouldn't be able to use them more than once.  Is there any practical way to accomplish that?

**Addendum**

In formulating a question, it's difficult sometimes to draw the line between complicated usage cases, and simpler usage cases which aren't quite so important.  Here's another usage case, and one closer to the one I'd be most interested in (though I'm also interested in Fluent chaining; being able to have something behave like a C++ reference to a value type would be nice, but probably too much work to bother with).

I have a type which is somewhat like the Windows registry, in that it is a hierarchical collection of items, each of which may have a string value, an integer value, and/or a nested collection of items.  I wish to be able to support the following types of usage:

```
// Store "George" as string in MyCollection!Wow
MyCollection["Wow"].st = "George"
// Store "George" as string in MyCollection!This!That
MyCollection["This"]["That"].i = 9
// Throws exception if ["Wow"] doesn't exist in collection
someInteger = MyCollection["This"]["That"].i
// Throws exception if ["This"]["That"] doesn't exist in collection
someString = MyCollection["Wow"].st
// Uses 9 as default value if it doesn't exist
someInteger = MyCollection["Whatever"].ii(9)
// Uses "George" as default if it doesn't exist
someString = MyCollection["Multi"]["Level"]["Path"].sst("George")
```

Being able to index things directly is very nice (the actual code is in VB, so it's possible to use the "!" syntax, for better or for worse--that's another story).  When evaluating a statement like:

```
MyCollection["This"]["that"].st = "George"
```

or

```
someString = MyCollection["This"]["that"].sst("George")
```

it's necessary to return some type of object for MyCollection["This"] without knowing whether the object will ultimately be used for reading or writing.  In the latter case, if MyCollection["This"] doesn't already exist, it will need to be created.  My present code simply creates the node regardless, but then tries to keep track of whether it "really" exists, which ends up being a nuisance.  Many of these objects get deep-cloned, so copy-on-write would be highly desirable, but when even reading a data structure can change it, copy-on-write ends up being highly impractical.

A somewhat cleaner solution would be to have the indexer return a data structure which indicates the collection being indexed and the key value, and then have whatever operation will ultimately be done on it (e.g. "st") do all of the necessary indexing.  This would improve the abstraction offered by the nested collection, and would also facilitate things like copy-on-write.  One caveat is that if someone were to do something like:

```
MyEvilVariable = MyCollection["This"];
MyEvilVariable["Nasty1"].st = "I'm evil"
MyEvilVariable["Nasty2"].st = "Really evil"
```

the second usage of MyEvilVariable could break the collection.

As for the Fluent interface, my thought would be to have the WithXXX properties return a new instance of a derived class which shadows (not overrides!) the WithXXX properties with versions that simply modify the current instance.  The return object from WithXXX would be known to be of the derived class, and would thus use the shadowed WithXXX methods, but once it was assigned to a variable, it would be regarded as an instance of the base class, so the next WithXXX would create a new instance.

C++ a stronger concept of value types than C# or vb.net, including the very useful concept of references to value types; it ensures that references to value types cannot be persisted outside the scope of the type in question.  Unsafe code in C# can use pointers to value types, but they don't have the protections offered by C++ references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is. If there were then I would never use such an abuse of language.

1. It could be even more efficient if WithXYZ(int,int,int) existed. Even better is to not worry about such efficiencies until you have measured that they are a significant issue.
2. Don't try and obfuscate things through "nice" syntax. Just treat things as they are and everyone will be much less confused overall.

Comment: 1. Obviously xyz would be a logical combination of things to do as a unit, but X, Y, and Z were simply chosen as arbitrary property names; there are many types of objects which have a wide variety of properties one might want to set. 2. There are many cases where it's necessary to copy an object before changing it if multiple references may exist, but where the object may be mutated if only one reference exists.  If there were a means of identifying at least some cases where only one reference could exist, that would seem useful.

Comment: @supercat - In most cases the "saving" achieved by mutating instead of copying will have an unnoticeable effect on the run time of the application. Do you actually have profiler results that disagree with this?

Comment: Since my development machine is rather different from many of the machines that will be running the code in production, it's difficult to profile (since caching behavior varies so enormously among machines).  At present I avoid chaining in many places because I know it won't be performant (deep cloning represents a non-trivial portion of run-time even though I use mutator methods directly in situations where I might otherwise use chaining).

Comment: Yours is the best response, though I don't think there's nothing wrong with wanting foo.x[y].z to be a property whose setter ties back to foo, performing something like foo.set_x_z(y,value), but whose getter works "normally", as distinct from having foo.x[y] be a stand-alone object which may be used separately from the expression.  That can be a useful abstraction in many situations, but it's somewhat leaky.  The inability of .net to define a custom conversion from a structure to an Object creates a weakness in the abstraction which is bigger than that posed by creating new variables.

Answer (score 3):

**Chaining** *aka Extension methods*

This is commonly used in jQuery (to pull a different language and framework that a lot of people have some familiarity with) and I've seen lots of people doing it in C# stuff. If you need to see more C# examples let me know and I can quote you some links.

```
public MyClass WithX(this MyClass myClass, int x) {
    myClass.X = x;
    return myClass;
}
```

You're passing in a MyClass (with the this) and you're returning a MyClass (which just happens to be the one you passed in). However the following example does not work:

```
myClass.WithX(x);
```

Because you're not updating the underlying object, you're returning it. I doubt you would be doing anything that simple anyways, so I'm just pointing out what you *could* and *couldn't* do.

---

**Class Indexer**

You can declare an indexer on any class, just be aware that you're likely going to mess with people. You do it like thus:

```
public string this[int x]{
    return "I don't care what you just gave me " + x;
}
```

However, to make it more complex like `foo[19].x = 9;` is going to be a little trickier, even tho you'll just be doing something akin to

```
public Foo this[int x]{
    return "I don't care what you just gave me " + x;
}
```

I say trick because I don't see where this *isn't* an array if you're doing it like this. What does 19 mean in this instance? Are you setting the value of X to 19 then 9? You're going to confuse a lot of people with this syntax.

Note that a class can only have one indexer (that I'm aware of).

---

**Some links:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx - Indexers

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx - Indexers

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx - Extension methods

Go crazy with the new knowledge and let me know what I'm missing or not explaining enough to get you started.

Comment: +1 for good info and warning how cryptic class indexing can get. I've done some pretty oddball stuff with indexing. ;)

Comment: An array of small mutable structs (e.g. Point) can hold information much more efficiently than an array of objects.  The usage `ArrayOfPoints[19].X = 9;` would be the normal way of setting the X coordinate of point 19 to the value nine.  To achieve analogous behavior with some other collection, `SomeOtherCollectionOfPoints["George"].X = 9;` seems more natural than `SetXCoordinateOfNamedPoint("George", 9);`

Comment: But that's _still_ an array yeah? You seemed to imply "not an array"

Comment: The data may be stored internally as an array, and outside access may be similar to an array, but that doesn't mean the class is going to expose its internal array directly.  Consider, for example, a ResizeableArray class, which holds a reference to an array and should be indexable like a normal array.  It would be nice to have such an array behave like a normal array of structs, including being able to set fields thereof, but such a thing ISN'T an array.

Comment: @drachenstern: The System.Array is a non-resizable indexable collection which exposes the items by reference (so one can pass IntArray[9] to Interlocked.CompareExchange, or write to fields of StructArray[3]).  No other collection can expose items by reference the way a System.Array can.  Saying that no other collection is an array isn't an "implementation detail"; a System.Array has some useful abilities which cannot be supported by any other collection.  The best one can do is try to simulate some behaviors by having a property return a class which holds a reference to the real item.

Comment: Ooooh, that I understand. Sorry.

Comment: @drachenstern: The only way a non-array-collection could expose items to CompareExchange would be for them to either provide a CompareExchange method, or provide a method to execute some externally-supplied routine with the item as a reference parameter.  Field access, however, could be kludged by having a property return a class which exported properties that were tied back to the original items (so foo[5] would yield a property which would hold a reference to foo, and the index 5, and whose "X" member would access the appropriate item within the collection and set its "X" property to 5.

Comment: @supercat ~ Well I'm with you now. So anyways, the code above (as far as I can tell) does what you need. lemme know if it doesn't, and I'll help where I can.

Comment: @drachenstern: The goal is to behave as though foo[5] is a reference to a value type, with the same semantics as though foo were an array of a value type.  Saying `myStruct=foo[5]; myStruct.X=9; foo[6]=myStruct;` should copy the structure in foo[5] to foo[6], but with the X value changed, and yet still allow foo[5].X to set the X value of a struct within foo.

Comment: @supercat Yes. Why can you not do that with the code I lisetd? Have you tried it? Is it time to start a new question referencing this one saying "Why doesn't my property indexer for my class work like I expect it to? (with code)" ... I don't understand what the problem here is. Did you try the code I presented? I've used it before (or something very similar).

Comment: @drachenstern: The first bit of code you gave above provides a means of giving a Fluent interface to structs; if used with a class, however, the WithX method would modify the value of the original instance, which may not be desirable.  My original question dealt with whether it was possible to have non-persistable types; Fluent interfaces and simulated-structure-array semantics were separate reasons for wanting such types.

Comment: @drachenstern: If the "get" method for an indexer returns a struct, the resulting struct is read-only, even if there also exists a "put" method.

Comment: @supercat So instead of returning the same object, create a new one, then return the new object... is it really so hard to do `MyClass returnValue = new MyClass(); returnValue = thisMyClass; returnValue.X = x; return returnValue;`? I don't understand the problem. I gave you the _way_ to write the code for the interface. You've proven you understand the internals of what you want it to do. Go on and write it and then come back with "this doesn't work, what's broken".

Comment: @supercat regarding "get" method for an indexer, would you like me to show you some classes that you can reflect and see how they did it? I use code all the time in the .NET that let's me `object[indexer][otherindexer].Value = value;`

Comment: @drachenstern: I guess my second point above wasn't clear.  A statement like "foo[19].X = 5;" is no problem if foo[19] is stored in an object instance which can be exposed to the public.  In that case, "foo[19]" returns that instance, and the code simply sets its X property/field to 5.  The difficulty comes if the indexer can't simply return an instance to an object it uses internally to hold the data (e.g. because the data is held in an array of Point).  If the caller merely gets a copy of the data, changes to that copy won't get written back to the original.

Comment: @supercat ~ It's up to you to figure out how to handle that, but ostensibly if the callee is exposing method X to the caller, then it will operate on the object held by callee. My advice, if you'll have it, is to test it with a bit of code, and show why it _doesn't_ work. Use dotnetpad if you like as a showcase to demonstrate.

Comment: @drachenstern: I'm not sure how to use dotnetpad as a "showcase", since it seems to be designed for one-off testing.  The difficulty is that there's no clean way for an object 'foo' to expose directly 'foo[someIndex].X' to the caller.  It can have foo[someIndex] return something with an 'X' property which can tie in with foo; this would be a very good exception if there were some way to prevent that thing from being persisted or boxed without being first cast to some other type.

Comment: @supercat ~ You write a basic console output only app and put it on dotnetpad and then others (such as myself) can run it and see what your code looks like and we can have a reference point for communication. Scan through some other recent posts on DNP and get a feel for how others use it. As for the cleanliness of exposing a foo element from the collection back to the caller, idk, I feel like you've already expressed that you know how to do that in conjunction with the code I posted. I'm not sure what you're being cautious about, just write what you think the code should be; let's start there

Comment: @jcolebrand: I just wrote something at http://dotnetpad.net/ViewPaste/l3kWau34NEekqbUcCkcmAg to show a different usage case for this concept.  If the only use of `OnlyRefArray` in outside code is to carry a the return value from `WithValue` to a call to exactly one of `OnlyRefArray`'s methods, then there will be no need to clone the array contained therein, either when mutating it again or storing it in a read-only wrapper to make it immutable.

Comment: @jcolebrand: Semantically, the return value from `WithValue` should behave as though it's immutable, but without the cost associated with operations on immutable objects.  A chained sequence of K simple operations on an array of size N would take O(k+n) rather than O(k*n); not a many-orders-of-magnitude savings, but not exactly trivial either.  Note too that the use of arrays and `Clone` was for simplicity; the principle is applicable to many types where producing an immutable collection encapsulating the result of many operations would be cheaper than producing an immutable result from each.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not define the constructer methods as internal? This should allow you to create objects inside your code but not outside of your code.

Comment: The issue isn't with creating objects outside the code, but rather with allowing outside code to persist a reference to an object.

Comment: If the code uses your object, they can persist a reference to it. That would be the nature of programming.

Comment: drachenstern: The issue is that the object may not be good for very long.  If an object Foo allows code to access Foo.x.y.z, the object returned by Foo.x has to be valid long enough to access Foo.x.y, but might be invalid after that (indeed, it might be invalidated by the access of Foo.x.y).  It would be nice to have a means of strongly suggesting that Foo.x shouldn't be persisted, since it's not going to be meaningful anyway.